# Align subplot axes in Bokeh when using Tabs and multiple y axes

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to create a figure in Bokeh with multiple subplots. Some of the subplots take advantage of the Tabs feature. Other subplots are just normal Figures but have an extra y axis. I can't get the right axes of the Figure objects and the Tab objects to align visually. The second y-axis essentially makes the subplot narrower and the other subplots shrink accordingly, but not the subplot with the tabs.

Currently, I'm using gridplot to put everything together. The issue must be related to the mixing of Tab and Figure objects, but I can't figure out how to properly make this layout work. I can kind of fudge it by adding "sizing_mode='stretch_width" as a gridplot argument, but this isn't ideal.

Here's an example code and the screenshot of the output:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LabelSet, HoverTool, Span, Range1d, LinearAxis
from bokeh.models import Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, gridplot
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column

import numpy as np

x = list(range(0,10))
y = list(range(0,10))
plot_height=200

fig1 = figure(plot_width=1250, plot_height=plot_height, title='Figure 1')
fig1.step(x,y, mode='after')
fig1.extra_y_ranges = {"y*10": Range1d(start=0, end=100)}
fig1.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="y*10", axis_label='y*10'), 'right')
fig1.step(x, np.array(y)*10, color='black', legend_label='y*10', y_range_name='y*10')

fig2a = figure(plot_width=1250, plot_height=plot_height, title='Figure 2')
fig2a.step(x,y)

fig2b = figure(plot_width=1250, plot_height=plot_height, title='Figure 2')
fig2b.step(x,y, line_width=4)

tabs = [Panel(child=fig2a, title='Normal'), Panel(child=fig2b, title='Bold')]
fig2 = Tabs(tabs=tabs)

fig3 = figure(plot_width=1250, plot_height=plot_height, title='Figure 3')
fig3.step(x,y)

fig4 = figure(plot_width=1250, plot_height=plot_height, title='Figure 4')
fig4.step(x,y)

o = gridplot([[fig1], [fig2], [fig3], [fig4]])

show(o)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFzxU.png)

Comment: Please supply the code that with `Tabs` that is not working, that is what would need to be diagnosed.

Comment: It already is included. See the lines that start with tabs = ... and fig2 = ...

The Tabs feature works fine, but when put into gridplot with a figure with an extra y axis, the right axes don't line up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: FWIW it is pretty unusual to refer to anything other than a plot as "fig" (short for figure).

I can state that there is nothing in Bokeh that will automatically align axes for things nested more than one level deep. In fact, I don't think putting tabs in gridplots was a use case that was ever even considered explicitly. I think your best option will be to manually supply a `min_border_right` value to the plots in the tabs, to force the right side to take up more empty space.

```py
fig2a = figure(..., min_border_right=80)
fig2b = figure(..., min_border_right=80)
```

The values above work "pretty well" but you will simply have to experiment to see what works best for you.

Note that the top toolbar will never line up in this configuration, since you have added an axis. It has to move to the right to accommodate the axis. You could consider moving the toolbars to the top of the plot.